# Laravel 5 QueryBuilder, resultados em coleção simplificada

Tags: php, laravel-5, querybuilder

Estou usando o método `get()` do QueryBuilder do Laravel e gostaria de saber se é possível retornar os id's em um simples array unidimensional, por exemplo:

```
[35,45]
```

Ao invés de:

```
[{"id":35},{"id":45}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesse caso você quer uma lista de id's.
Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
$ids= DB::table('minha_tabela')->pluck('id');
```

Você pode ver isso na [documentação aqui.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries)

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

QueryBuilder é um Framework que dispõe de uma interface para construção de consultas sql e sua principal caraterística é a abstração das plataformas de banco de dados. Acredito que ele não possua ferramentas para manipulação de coleções, mas você pode resolver seu problema fazendo um mapping na coleção.

Utilizando a função `array_map` do *PHP* passe uma *Closure* seguida da coleção que você deseja mapear implementando o retorno do atributo desejado.

Exemplo:

```
$listaIds = array_map(function($obj){
                return $obj->id;
            }, $listaObjetos);
```